# How to pattern match a string based on a character?

Tags: scala

In my code, a string is expected to have the following structure `part1-part2-part3`. The different parts are separated by `-` and there can only be 3 parts.

So far I have used `split` method of `String` and can check the length of the returned `Array` to validate the structure:

```
val tagDetails: Array[String] = tag.split('-') //syntax of received tag is part1-part2-part3

if (tagDetails.length == 3) {
  val course: String = tagDetails(0)
  val subject: String = tagDetails(1)
  val topic: String = tagDetails(2)
  println("splitted tag " + course + ", " + subject + ", " + topic) 
} else {..}
```

How can I do the same using `match`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can destructure the Array of splitted values with `match`.

```
val tag = "course-subject-topic"

tag.split('-') match {
  case Array(course, subject, topic) =>
    println("splitted tag " + course + ", " + subject + ", " + topic)
  case _ => println("Oops")
}
```

pattern match can also have `if` guard as below,

```
tag.split('-') match {
  case Array(course, subject, topic) if course != subject =>
    println("splitted tag " + course + ", " + subject + ", " + topic)
  case _ => println("Oops")
}
```

Reference - https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 5):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to pattern match a `String` by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
"part1-part2-part3" match {
  case s"$course-$subject-$topic" =>
    println(s"Split tag $course, $subject, $topic")
  case _ =>
    println("Oops")
}
// Splitted tag part1, part2, part3
```